# Spring batch job state configured to alert with prometheus

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, alert, prometheus

We are using Spring batch framework for project. Can I configure prometheus (https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/alerting/#alerting) with my spring batch framework. In prometheus docs, I can see an example of Spring boot only. Any help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2774 for updates about micrometer integration in Spring Batch.

Comment: Thanks for update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Batch does not have Micrometer integration at this time.  It's something we're evaluating for a future release.  Feel free to open an issue if you are interested!